# Getting "No adapter attached; skipping layout" error when parsing a named JSON inside another list

Tags: android, retrofit, adapter

I want to parse some [JSON (Car models)](https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/59/modelos):

```
{"modelos": [{"nome": AMAROK},{"nome": JETTA}]}
```

I have the code below: ADAPTER

```
public class ListaVeiculosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListaVeiculosAdapter.ListaVeiculosViewHolder> {

private List<VeiculosResponse> veiculos;

public ListaVeiculosAdapter(List<VeiculosResponse> veiculos) {
    this.veiculos = veiculos;
}

public ListaVeiculosAdapter() {

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListaVeiculosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_veiculo, parent, false);

    return new ListaVeiculosViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListaVeiculosViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textNomeVeiculo.setText(veiculos.get(position).getNome());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (veiculos!= null && veiculos.size()>0) ? veiculos.size() : 0;
}

static class ListaVeiculosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView textNomeVeiculo;

    public ListaVeiculosViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        textNomeVeiculo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_veiculo);
    }

}}
```

Main Activity:

```
RecyclerView recyclerVeiculos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_veiculos);

    // Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerVeiculos = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    ListaVeiculosAdapter adapter = new ListaVeiculosAdapter();
    ApiService.getInstance().getModels().enqueue(new Callback<VeiculosResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<VeiculosResult> call, Response<VeiculosResult> response) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ListaVeiculosActivity.this);
            recyclerVeiculos.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerVeiculos.setAdapter(new ListaVeiculosAdapter(response.body().getModelos()));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<VeiculosResult> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}}
```

The problem is that I get the error

```
"E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"
```

when I try to run the application.

Other Retrofit configuration codes:

```
public interface VeiculosService {
    @GET("marcas/59/modelos")
    Call<VeiculosResult> getModels();
}


    private static VeiculosService INSTANCE;

public static VeiculosService getInstance() {
    if(INSTANCE == null){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/")
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

        INSTANCE = retrofit.create(VeiculosService.class);
     }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

My idea is to create a list (recycler view) with car models so the user can choose which car they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `set layout manager` and `set adapter` to your `recyclerview` before API call.

Modify your `MainActivity` like this.

```
 RecyclerView recyclerVeiculos;
 List<VeiculosResponse> veiculos;
 ListaVeiculosAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_veiculos);

    // Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerVeiculos = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(ListaVeiculosActivity.this);
    recyclerVeiculos.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    // create an empty list and pass it to your adapter
    veiculos = new ArrayList<>()
    adapter = new ListaVeiculosAdapter(veiculos)
    recyclerVeiculos.setAdapter(adapter);

    ApiService.getInstance().getModels().enqueue(new Callback<VeiculosResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<VeiculosResult> call, Response<VeiculosResult> response) {
           if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null){
                veiculos.addAll(response.body().getModelos());
               // after getting new data you have to notify your adapter that your data set is changed like below.
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<VeiculosResult> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });





// ...
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much! I have another question: this recycler view will be used to the user choose the car model. The first JSON has almost the same endpoint as i placed above..   https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas . Is there a way to put this list that is on the recycler view into a drop down list ? I will use the data choosen by the first “question” to modify the query to the second question about the models. (Using @path on retrofit).

Comment: Yes it is possible by using `spinner` you can see this example [android-spinner-drop-down-list-example](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/). OR [spinner  with custom adapter example](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html)

Comment: I am glad that my answer helps you, you can accept this answer. so other users get it useful. `Happy Coding`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what has been stated by @Jakir will sort out the skipping adpter issue. This mostly occurs when there is an issue with how you are attaching adapter to recyclerView.

```
//Set layoutmanager attaching adapter to recyclerView
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(myLayoutManager)
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

myAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

Then for the json response you need to create a pojo classes for it.
This will fetch the array of Json objects. ModelusData class will now contain the individual modelus info

```
public class ModelusObject { 
@SerializedName("modelus")
private List<ModelusData> list; 
public List<ModelusData> getList() { 
    return list; 
} 
public void setList(List<ModelusData> list) { 
    this.list = list; 
} 
}
```

For the ModelusData class

```
public class ModelusData{
    @SerializedName("nome")
     String nome; 
    @SerializedName("codigo") 
    String codigo;
    public String getNome() {
         return nome;
    } 
    public void setNome(String nome) { 
        this.nome = nome;
    } 
     public String getCodigo() { 
        return codigo; 
    }
    public void setCodigo(String codigo) { 
        this.codigo = codigo; 
    }
}
```